# What is an appropriate 4G/LTE repeater for home use?

Tags: wireless, 4g

Inside our house I only usually get an H or H+ signal, or sometimes 3G but when I go outside, I get a fast 4G signal. I plan to buy a repeater so that I will get the same 4G signal inside.

I already have seen a repeater in an online shop and it's quite affordable at $50. However it says it is a GSM900MHz repeater.

My question is: can it detect the 4G signal outside and repeat the 4G inside our house?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the product you found?

Comment: I hope I won't violate any rules. Anyway, here is the link http://www.ebay.com/itm/LS4G-Phone-Signal-Repeater-Booster-Amplifier-Yagi-Antenna-LCD-GSM-900MHz-Kit-/401047312952?hash=item5d60485a38:g:MxIAAOSw5IJWgK7l

Comment: Your wireless carriers might be able to provide you a Signal Extender. I understand you are looking for a repeater, but depending on your carrier, they may lend you an extender for free. You can try out